# (Python/tqdm) Getting all zeros in timer when working with Pandas

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm trying to display a progress bar whenever a file is loaded into pandas. But all I get back is this.

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
```

Here is the code I'm working with.

I'm importing tqdm based on some examples that I've found.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
...

def function(self):
    params = self.getGuiParams()
    filename = params['fileNameLineEdit']
    keyname = params['dataSetNameLineEdit']
    try:
        print('Loading data file: ' + str(filename))
        self.datakeys.append(keyname)
        chunksize = 50000
        df = tqdm(pd.read_csv(filename, header=[0, 1], chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True))
        self.data[keyname] = spectral_data(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Problem reading data: {}'.format(e))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tqdm` requires an iterator. While you are using the `iterator=True` option for `read_csv`, you are assigning the resulting `TextFileReader` object back to `df`, without actually iterating on it.

Try something like:

```
tfr = pd.read_csv(filename, header=[0, 1], chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True
with tqdm() as pbar:
  # do something with the chunk
  pbar.update()
```

I've never used tqdm so that may not work out of the box - you might need to calculate file size and how many chunks that will take etc.

Comment: I'm getting a `AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'columns'` error. What does this mean?

Comment: Without knowing more, the TextFileReader object does not have an attribute named 'columns' - but you're trying to access it via `tfr.columns`

Comment: Check out the docs for `TextFileReader`, and how to use iterate over the chunks it reads from the file. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking

Comment: Would also be interested to find out how to implement this. I also would like to use `tqdm` for loading an hdf5 file with pandas with `pd.read_hdf`. Has someone figured this out ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, that manually updates the `tqdm` progress bar, I'd like to suggest an alternative that might be a little more intuitive:

```py
text_file_reader = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True)
for chunk in tqdm(text_file_reader):
    # chunk is a pd.DataFrame with *chunksize* rows of pd.read_csv(filename)
    # (the last chunk might have fewer rows)

    # do something with the chunk
```

This will not give you a standard progress bar slowly filling up to 100%. Instead, you will get information about how many chunks were already processed and what their average processing time was: like so:

```
18/? [00:22<00:00, 1.29s/it]
```

One might be able to fill the progress bar with meaningful data - however, as I see it this would require some kind of estimate of number or rows from file size which doesn't seem trivial to me.

Comment: Thank you for adding an additional answer. This is an old question, but your solution is definitely clever.